# Using "this" from event handler in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following javascript code found also in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/periklis/k4u4c/

```
<button id = "element_id" class = "myclass">Click me</button>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        this.myfunc = function() {
            console.log('Hello world');
        }
        this.myfunc();
        $('#element_id').select('.myclass').bind('click', function() {
            this.myfunc(); //Obviously this doesn't work
        });
    });
</script>​
```

How can I call this.myfunc() when the element is clicked? I don't want to define the myfunc() in the global space.

Thanks as always

Comment: Cache `this` in a variable, say, `var that = this;`. http://jsfiddle.net/k4u4c/1/

Comment: *I don't want to define the myfunc() in the global space.*: Assigning the function to a property of `document` is not very good either. Just create a local variable in that function. The event handler is a closure and therefore has access to all variables you declare in the ready event handler.

Comment: @FelixKling: I just wrote an answer along those lines after it seemed the first few hadn't picked up on that. :) Its always important to know what `this` refers to in any given context. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a local variable that references to the function, that way it is accessible from the anonymous function and you don't end up with `myfunc` in the global namespace.

```
<button id = "element_id" class = "myclass">Click me</button> 
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        var myfunc = function() { 
            console.log('Hello world'); 
        } 
        myfunc(); 
        $('#element_id').select('.myclass').bind('click', function() { 
            myfunc(); // works!
        }); 
    }); 
</script>​
```

If you, on the other hand, assign `var that = this;`, then your method `myfunc` will be stored on the HTMLDocument object (from `$(document)`), which is perhaps not what you want. But if that's what you want, then you do this (as others have suggested also, I might add).

```
<button id = "element_id" class = "myclass">Click me</button> 
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        // storing reference to $(document) in local variable
        var that = this;
        // adding myfunc on to the document object
        that.myfunc = function() { 
            console.log('Hello world'); 
        } 
        that.myfunc(); 
        $('#element_id').select('.myclass').bind('click', function() { 
            that.myfunc(); // works!
        }); 
    }); 
</script>​
```

// Simon A

Answer (score 2):

You could do

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var that = this;
    that.myfunc = function() {
        console.log('Hello world');
    }
    that.myfunc();
    $('#element_id').select('.myclass').bind('click', function() {
        that.myfunc();
    });
});
```

In this way you cache the `this` variable with something that you can reuse in your event handlers where `this` points to the current element

Answer (score 2):

You may be a little confused by what you are doing with the `this.myfunc` call.

In that context `this` is referring to `document` which means you are globally defining that function and it can be referenced at any time by `document.myfunc();`

If you are just wanting to put a function in a variable temporarily then the following code should help:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        this.myfunc = function() {
            alert('Hello world');
        };
     var otherfunc = function() {
            alert('Hi world');
        };
     $('.cv1').click(document.myfunc);
     $('.cv2').click(otherfunc);
 });
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LKmuX/

This demonstrates both what you are doing in terms of attaching a function to document and also just putting it in a variable.

Comment: This is interesting; I thought that this would refer to the anonymous function, not the document itself

Comment: @periklis: A quick google turned up http://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/jquerys-this-demystified/ which will probably explain things better than I would. Essentially though `this` is referring to whatever dom element is being acted on by the function. So in this case the anonymous function is the event handler attached to `document` so `this` is `document`

Comment: @periklis: In jQuery, `this` always refers to the element you bound the handler to. In general, `this` never refers to the function itself if you don't set it explicitly, i.e. you'd have to call the function with `func.call(func)`.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to caching the context, if you need to use the external context inside the binded function, is to use the `proxy()` method (docs [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)) to change the scope of the internal function like this :

```
$('#element_id').select('.myclass').bind('click', $.proxy(function() {
    this.myfunc();
}, this));
```

In this way, I force the actual `this` (the context when I'm using the bind method) to be the same inside the binded function (that normally has his own context)

http://jsfiddle.net/k4u4c/2/

---

FYI - the same method can be found in Dojo library (in Dojo it's
largely used), and it's called [hitch](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/hitch.html)

Answer (score 0):

Most common way to do this is to *cache* `this` in other variable and later on in handler refer to that variable as you would do with `this`. http://jsfiddle.net/k4u4c/3/

```
<button id = "element_id" class = "myclass">Click me</button>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        this.myfunc = function() {
            console.log('Hello world');
        }
        this.myfunc();
            var that = this;
        $('#element_id').select('.myclass').bind('click', function() {
            that.myfunc(); //Obviously this DOES work :)
        });
    });
</script>​
```